# Сохранение из Xml файла в базу данных mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, ado.net, datagridview

Добрый день! Прошу сразу не кидать камнями. Для лабораторной работы необходимо импортировать и экспортировать данные из таблицы базы данных.
Считываю следующим образом.

```
string sql;
        string bd;
        if (i == 1)
        {
            sql = "SELECT * FROM группы";
            bd = "группы";
        }
        else if (i == 2)
        {
            sql = "Insert";
            bd = "студенты";
        }
        else
        {
            sql = "SELECT * FROM факультеты";
            bd = "факультеты";
        }

        using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString))
        {


            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
                XmlReader xmlFile;
                xmlFile = XmlReader.Create("usersdb.xml", new XmlReaderSettings());
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                ds.ReadXml(xmlFile);
                dg.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

                adapter.Update(ds);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }



        }
```

Но ни как не получается занести эти данные в бд. Посоветуйте пожалуйста!
Пробую считать в datagridviewи после отправить в бд.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {

            dl.PrintValues(dataGridView1, 1);
        }
        else if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            dl.PrintValues(dataGridView1, 2);

        }
        else
        {
            dl.PrintValues(dataGridView1, 3);

        }

        try
        {
            var result = new ArrayList();

            for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                var row = new ArrayList();

                for (int j = 0; j <= dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells.Count - 1; j++)
                {

                    row.Add(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value);

                }

                result.Add(row);

            }

            MessageBox.Show("Изменения в базе данных выполнены!",
             "Уведомление о результатах", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Изменения в базе данных выполнить не удалось!",
              "Уведомление о результатах", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }
```

этот код должен был вставить все записи из xml  файла.
[image: Ошибка при запуске]

Comment: Каким образом нужно занести данные в БД, в какую таблицу/процедуру? Приведите код Вашей попытки и укажите что именно не получается

Comment: есть таблица студентов которая хранит различного рода информацию. Каким образом?-любым возможным,лучше не сложный!

Comment: Вроде приведенный код никак не связан с MySQL. Покажите именно как пытались вставить данные в БД. Если ничего не пробовали, то вбейте в поисковик запрос «mysql с использованием c# вставка» и посмотрите примеры.

Comment: Изменил! код. Просмотрите пожалуйста!

Comment: Напишите что этот код должен был сделать (если вставить данные то какие и куда) и что не получилось.

Comment: Выложил ошибку и код

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71169/discussion-between---and-default-locale).